# Duda en agrupaciones de csv con pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, group-by

Tengo un csv con películas y series y quiero agruparlos por año y tipo y que además que contenga un filtro de año.

Con el siguiente código:

```
data = df.release_year[df.release_year > 2000].groupby(df.type).value_counts()
print(data)
```

Obtengo:

```
type     release_year    count
Movie    2017            744
         2018            734
         ...
         2021             12
TV Show  2020            457
         2019            414
         2018            387
         ...
         2021             19
```

He conseguido sacar mi listado, pero la primera agrupación es por tipo y me gustaría que fuera en primer lugar por año. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Busco que quede así:

```
release_year    type    count
2017            Movie   744
                TV Show 650
2018            Movie   500
                TV Show 200
 ...
```

**Edito:**
El dataframe es tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
show_id type        title                   release_year
1       Movie       10 Days in Sun City     2017
2       TV Show     10 jours                2012
3       TV Show     100 Days My Prince      2018
4       Movie       100 Days Of Solitude    2020
...
```

Comment: Buen día, si agregas los datos que usas para el dataframe será más fácil que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Hola @heytalePAzguato , He intentado simplicarlo. he añadido un ejemplo de las columnas del dataframe. No se adjuntarlo, pero el resto de los datos no creo que sean relevantes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar el método `groupby`. En los argumentos puedes pasar las columnas que deseas que se utilicen para agrupar el dataframe en el orden que las deseas

Si utilizas la siguiente línea de código:

```
df.groupby(['release_year', 'type', 'title']).count()
```

Obtienes lo siguiente (Tuve que inventar filas para que se viera mejor):

```
release_year    type    title
2000            Movie   l
2003            Movie   m
2004            TV Show n
2005            Movie   h
2011            TV Show g
2012            Movie   d
                TV Show 10 jours
                        c
                        j
2014            Movie   a
                TV Show o
2015            Movie   p
                TV Show b
2017            Movie   10 Days in Sun City
2018            Movie   e
                        i
                TV Show 100 Days my Prince
2020            Movie   100 Days Of Solitude
                TV Show f
2021            TV Show k
```

**EDICIÓN:**

Para filtrar el nuevo grupo puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
df[df.release_year > 2015].groupby(['release_year', 'type', 'title']).count()
```

Salida:

```
release_year    type    title
2017            Movie   10 Days in Sun City
2018            Movie   e
                        i
                TV Show 100 Days my Prince
2020            Movie   100 Days Of Solitude
                TV Show f
2021            TV Show k
```

Comment: Hola @HeytalePazguato, no me sirve exactamente. Es decir, esto funciona, pero pierdo el filtro del año. Lo que necesito es combinarlo y además que me realice el conteo. Tanto si en mi codigo cañado la segunda columna en el groupby, como en el tuyo añado el filtro del año me da error.

Comment: @Maggie, edité la respuesta, el filtro sigue funcionando igual que en un dataframe normal, lo único que hacemos con `groupby` es agrupar el resultado del filtro. Saludos

Comment: Genial, lo que no me  quedaba claro era poder combinar los dos y como unirlo con los corchetes y despues el .groupby     Mil gracias! Voy a seguir practicando combinaciones :)